# Is there a formula to line up column rows based on cell value or partial value?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet with 4 columns, see screenshot_1

- Column `A` - word
- Column `C` - word (column `A`) + extra word

The rows of Column `A` and column `C` and their values (column B and D) are not lined up. As you can see in the screenshot,

I want to place `C2` And `D2` on line 29, `C3` and `D3` on line 15, etc. So column `C` and `D` are filled with the matching word of column `A` (if it exists).

Resulting in something like screenshot_2

Is there a formula to line up column rows based on cell value or partial value?

- [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afzTK.png)
- [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4OY3.png)

Comment: If you want to move `C2 & D2` to `C29 & D29` respectively then formula is not an option and you'll have to use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using wildcard in Vlookup. Enter this formula  `=VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",$F$2:$G$26,2,FALSE)` in column `C`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest solution would be to keep columns A and B untouched, and have column C automatically display "used (whatever)" if column D contains a number.

To accomplish this, type the following formula into cell C2 and drag down:

```
= IF(ISNUMBER(D2),"used "&A2,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, separate the ranges with some empty columns; so column A & is the same, C is empty, D & E are a not connected

Create a new column in the empty C column:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&A2&"*",F:F,0),VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",F:G,2,0),""),"")
```

[See this Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZBgg.png)